# progress bar click => change current track play position

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

i am making a music player in winforms. i have a progress bar and when i click on a position along the progress bar, i want to get the int for that position ( from 1 to 100 , i.e. for when i want to get to a certain point in my song ) . How can i do that ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: You should probably use a slider instead of a progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use a picturebox to simulate a progress bar ... have a method to partially fill it based on current progress, and wire up the MouseDown event (this will provide you with the mouse position which you can then scale accordingly).

Answer (score 3):

Use [TrackBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) control, and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gTrackBar.aspx) is may an advance one, I hope it helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks ! i'll try it first thing in the morning !

Comment: :@Badescu Alexandru: Welcome, but don't forget to give my answer the accept if it works ;) :D, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
'Using The Click or MouseDown or any Mouse Event

Dim Value As Integer= Me.PointToClient(MousePosition).X-Progressbar.Bounds.X

Progressbar.value= Value
```

Comment: This one should be marked as this is the closest solution according to the question. But this code brings up an absolute Value for the mouse-position. Better would be converting it to an relative value which range is 0 to 100. Check my incoming answer. Upvoted for the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a control  that have to be placed on the progress bar --like a small bullet .
now if you use the code

```
progressbar1.value=control.location.x/y
```

place the name of the control at the position of control x/y decides the coordinates.

make a note that you have to  move the control on the progress bar for simplifications use a picture box and  use the keydown event to move it side by side

Answer (score 1):

This one brings up a value in relation to the position where the click was done on the progressbar. The value range here is calculated from 0 to 100%. Its also in relation to the width of the progressbar so the range will stay fixed to percentage logic.

```
private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get mouse position(x) minus the width of the progressbar (so beginning of the progressbar is mousepos = 0 //
            float absoluteMouse = (PointToClient(MousePosition).X - progressBar1.Bounds.X);
            // Calculate the factor for converting the position (progbarWidth/100) //
            float calcFactor = progressBar1.Width / (float)progressBar1.Maximum;
            // In the end convert the absolute mouse value to a relative mouse value by dividing the absolute mouse by the calcfactor //
            float relativeMouse = absoluteMouse / calcFactor;

            // Set the calculated relative value to the progressbar //
            progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(relativeMouse);
        }
```

**I know this question was asked a long time ago, but it was out of the right solution. Here it is now.**